# Default GHC flags with Haskell Stack

Tags: haskell, configuration, haskell-stack, compiler-flags

I wanted to set some custom compiler flags for all stack-compiled packages on my machine (more aggressive optimizations than the defaults), and following the [stack guide](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/), I added some `ghc-options` (applying to `"$everything"`) to my `~/.stack/config.yaml`. These flags were properly applied to `stack` invocations outside of any project directory.

Within project directories, however, the `stack.yaml` options don't just take precedence; everything in `~/.stack/config.yaml` is completely ignored! I have no `ghc-options` specified in any project-local `stack.yaml` files, but those specified `~/.stack/config.yaml` have no effect.

The [`stack` documentation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/architecture/#configuration) would seem to suggest that options should collapse, as I had expected them to:

> stack has two layers of configuration: project and non-project. All of these are stored in stack.yaml files, but the former has extra fields (resolver, packages, extra-deps, and flags). **The latter can be monoidally combined so that a system config file provides defaults, which a user can override with ~/.stack/config.yaml, and a project can further customize.**

Unless I have a very different idea of what "customize" means, this isn't the behavior I'm observing. Is there something I'm doing incorrectly, or is the documentation misleading in this respect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, I consider this to be a bug.  I have a PR that hasn't been merged yet that fixes it https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/pull/3781